# react-script-build Error permission dienied copyfile from public to build folder

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I was facing the issue, so i used the following commands to fix it. basically giving full access to the folder.

`sudo chmod -R 777 /yourDirectoryName`
Or
`sudo chmod -R 777 ./`